# Gandi Domain Name to OVH web host: mails are not delivered

Tags: email, web-hosting, domain-name

I recently moved a web site to a new web host (OVH), while keeping the same domain name (handled by Gandi for a while).

In the Gandi configuration panel I modified the name servers, so they point to the right OVH name servers.

After the site data/database has been successfully transfered, the site is working well, but mails
do not deliver at all.

On the OVH side (web host):

- MX fields are present and point to `mx*.mail.ovh.net` (initial configuration)
- I setup a mail address to be redirected to my personnal mail

But I don't receive any mail. Is there something evident I could have missed about the
configuration?

Comment: ps: I posted a ticket on ovh, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have same problem with OVH, mails are no longer delivered if sended from PHP hosting, support says that they do not resolve missconfiguration in code.. Did you resolve somehow?

Comment: I solved it, but I'm not sure the exact reason because I tried many things at the same time; but I read (old) articles which said that OVH mails had been blacklisted by gmail. So in the OVH mail redirection section, I changed my gmail address to another one, in another domain. I *think* this is what solved the issue.